# How can we fetch the OTP from DB in selenium webdriver java

Tags: java, database, selenium, selenium-webdriver, one-time-password

Can we automate OTP using selenium webdriver ? Is there any example code logic to try on how can we fetch the OTP received in mobile from DB in order to enter in website . Appreciate any leads. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Selenium has nothing to do with databases. You'll need another technology. For those purposes use JDBC. See https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm.

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
        <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>8.4.1.jre8</version>
</dependency>
```

Or add JDBC jars to your project.

Let's say DB is on SQL Server Express with Windows authentication, DB name is 'MyDatabase' and the table named 'OTP' with OTPs looks like this:

[image: table example]

Using JDBC:

```
package db;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class OtpManager {

    public static Connection connectSqlDb(String dbName) throws SQLException {
        String serverName = "PC NAME\\SQLEXPRESS";
        return DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlserver://" + serverName + ";databaseName=" + dbName + ";integratedSecurity=true");
    }
    
    public static String getLastOptForUser(String userName) throws SQLException {
        String otp = null;
        Connection connection = connectSqlDb("MyDatabase");
        Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
        String query = "select top (1) otp from [MyDatabase].[dbo].[OTP] where username = '" + userName + "' order by created desc";
        ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery(query);
        while(result.next()) {
            otp = result.getString("otp");
        }
        return otp;
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
        String userName = "user1";
        String lastOtp = getLastOptForUser(userName);
        System.out.println(lastOtp);
    }
    
}
```

Output:

```
2222
```

In your selenium tests you can than use the OTP value: `element.sendKeys(String string);`